# Solve the equation: $\left|3^x - x\right|\left|3^x + x - 4\right| = 49$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, roots

I want to solve the equation in $\mathbb{R}$:
$$ \left|3^x - x\right|\left|3^x + x - 4\right| = 49 $$

***My attempt:***

The above equation is the same as:
$$ \left(3^x - x\right)\left(3^x + x - 4\right) = \pm 49 $$

*Case 1:* $\left(3^x - x\right)\left(3^x + x - 4\right) = 49$

By taking derivative of the LHS, I managed to prove that it is monotonically increasing. Therefore, the equation has at most $1$ solution. By plugging in $\space x = 2,\space$ the equation is satisfied, so the first solution is $\space x = 2$.

*Case 2:* $\left(3^x - x\right)\left(3^x + x - 4\right) = -49$

I was not able to guess any integer nor rational solutions to this case, so I have to expand it:
$$ x^2 - 4x + 4 \times 3^x - 3^{2x} = 49 $$
$$ (x - 2)^2 - \left(3^x - 2\right)^2 = 49 $$
This is where I got stuck and could not go further for a long time. I plugged it in WolframAlpha and received one solution: $\space x \approx -5.27928$.

I would like to know how to solve this equation appropriately, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for integer solutions?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah No, I want to find real solutions.

Comment: I suspect the solutions are transcendental and involves Lambert W-function.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with what you have done. There is an integer value of x which satisfies the solution for x >= 0. Even for x < 0, there is only one value that satisfies the equation but x is not an integer. For x < 0 also, the function is monotonically increasing as (3^x -2) will be between -1 and -2 for x < 0.

Comment: To @KM02: are you familiar with numerical method for solving non-linear equations?

Comment: Rep @AntonVrdoljak: Yes, I know how Newton method works. However, I am interested in finding the exact form of the solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with special functions, you could not get an explicit solution for the zero of function
$$f(x)=(x - 2)^2 - \left(3^x - 2\right)^2 - 49$$ and you will need some numerical method.

If you plot the function for $-6 \leq x \leq -5$, you will have a good surprise since, over that range $f(x)$ is very linear and this is very good for Newton method for example (or for any root-finding procedure). This is normal because $3^{-5}=\frac{1}{243} \ll 2$. So, for the time being, ignore that term and you will have
$$x_0=2-\sqrt{53}\approx -5.28011$$

Making one single iteration of Newton method wiil give
$$x_1=2-\sqrt{53}+\frac{9 \left(4\ 3^{\sqrt{53}}-9\right)}{2 \left(81 \log
   (3)+3^{\sqrt{53}} \left(3^{\sqrt{53}} \sqrt{53}-18 \log (3)\right)\right)}\approx -5.27928$$

Now, if you really want to polish the solution, continue ierating to get
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & \color{red}{-5.2}8010988928051827109730249152703279377766968257647743837818 \\
 1 & \color{red}{-5.2792786}8660406789534055303817937109818859725033462499045920 \\
 2 & \color{red}{-5.279278638758321}32633710054196086428743183092915950945577438 \\
 3 & \color{red}{-5.27927863875832116780469489398033}721735193951378723970745104 \\
 4 & \color{red}{-5.27927863875832116780469489398033547687818546758970688733708}
\end{array}
\right)$$

which, amuzing but with no meaning at all, is close to
$$10\left(\sin \left(\frac{8 \pi }{59}\right)-\cos \left(\frac{9 \pi }{82}\right) \right)=-5.2792786221$$

Comment: Thanks for your amazing answer, but can you elaborate on why we could not get an explicit solution for the equation?

Comment: @KM02. Because it is transcental. Remember that $x=\cos(x)$ does not show analytical solution. Cheers :-)